# How can I automate the turret to face the target within a distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First a screenshot describe the turret structure. I'm not sure what parts should I rotate and how.
I want the turret to rotate all directions 360 degrees.
I have one script attached to one of the child that make the turret rotate.
And one script on the enemy object a 3d cube that move around the turret.

What I'm trying to do is that if the enemy is close enough to the turret so the turret will get in action and try to shoot on the enemy.

This screenshot is showing the turret structure in the hierarchy and the script attached to it and the enemy 3d cube :

[Turret and enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLXP9.jpg)

This is the script attached to the turret : Sentry_Turn_01 child object :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Turn_Move : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int TurnX;
    public int TurnY;
    public int TurnZ;
    public int MoveX;
    public int MoveY;
    public int MoveZ;
    public bool World;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (World == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime, TurnY * Time.deltaTime, TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime, TurnY * Time.deltaTime, TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

And this script is attached to the enemy :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;

    private int _minY, _maxY;
    private int _targetHeight;
    private const float Tolerance = 0.1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        _minY = (int)54.49f;
        _maxY = 150;
        _targetHeight = Random.Range(_minY, _maxY);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var randomSpeed = Random.Range(0.1f, 0.3f);
        transform.Rotate(0, randomSpeed, 0);
        if (System.Math.Abs(transform.position.y - _targetHeight) < Tolerance)
            _targetHeight = Random.Range(_minY, _maxY);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, _targetHeight, transform.position.z), randomSpeed / 10f);
        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, target.transform.up, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have the turret look at the enemy.

Comment: @BugFinder I tried it now. The problem is seems that the blue axis face the target but the gun of the turret is facing the red axis. My guess is something wrong with the turret model. How can I fix it ? https://imgur.com/a/6hXhEGG

Comment: @BugFinder and when using LookAt it's just facing all the time to the target so if the gun will shoot it will always hit the target. Is that a good logic ai of the turret ?

Comment: @BugFinder The main goal is to make the turret defending and shooting enemy planes/scifi space ships that coming randomly in waves. Tried to search for tutorials about that but I didn't find any. Mostly are for tower defence. but in tower defence the turrets never miss and in my case I want to make that sometimes the turrets miss.